# TYPO3: Extbase get related pages by sys_categories

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I need to get page media and excerp of a random page that has one or more sys_categories in common with the recent page.

I tried getting the cat ids for a where clause like so:

```
$categories = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->page['categories'];
$cats = explode(',',$categories);
foreach($cats as $cat) {
    if($whereClauses != '') $whereClauses .= " OR ";
    $whereClauses .= $cat.' IN pages.categories';
}
```

But I did not get this working as the where clause of `$this->pageRepository->getRecordsByField`
hope anyone can help me out accessing the page.

It's a 7.6.x TYPO3 and extbase

Answer (score 2):

The categories are assigned in an MM Relation Table (`sys_category_record_mm`), so the categories are not saved in pages table.

So you have to query this table to get pages assigned to an category.

eg:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECT_mm_query('*', 'sys_category', 'sys_category_record_mm', 'pages', 'tablenames = "pages" AND sys_category.uid = 123')
```

**EDIT:** Example of Usage with `CategoryCollection`:

```
$collection = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Category\Collection\CategoryCollection::load($id, false, 'pages');
$items = $collection->getItems();
```

Comment: You two are right. i already tested it like that:
        `$pid = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->page['uid'];
        $query = \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\CategoryRepository::createQuery();

        $query->statement("SELECT uid_local FROM sys_category_record_mm
      WHERE
      tablenames = 'pages'
      AND
      uid_foreign = ".$pid);
        $categories = $query->execute();`
But failing to get the page by the cats.

Comment: I don't think that you can fetch the pages from categories with some extbase stuff.

You can try to use the `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Category\Collection\CategoryCollection` to get pages.

Comment: I have added some example code for CategoryCollection.

Answer (score 0):

`pages.categories` only contains the number of categories the page is assigned to.

The actual category IDs are in an mm-table `sys_category_record_mm`.